# Javascript Iframe weekday

Tags: javascript, iframe

the question on the assignment asks to insert a command to write the HTML code

to the webpage where weekday is the text string returned by the weekDay() function.

The iframe should display the daily schedules that are stored in the sunday.htm through saturday.htm file.

The weekDay() function is located in an external .js file that I have already linked to my webpage.

Another thing is there is no weekday.htm file instead there are files sunday.htm through saturday.htm that have the daily schedules to de displayed in the iframe.

I know that I should some link the weekday.htm file to the weekDay() function. This is what I have done so far:

```
<h2 id="title">Today at the Union</h2>

<p>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
Dispaly the daily schedule in an inline frame. 
Display schedules are stored in the files     
sunday.htm through saturday.htm
*/

<iframe src='weekday.htm'>

var weekday = weekDay();
document.write(weekday);
</iframe>
</script>
</p>
```

Please advice as to how to get this thing working. I am not an expert( I am still learning.) I tried my best (spent several hours breaking my head on this). So any help is much appreciated.

Thank you for your time

Comment: `<iframe>` is an HTML tag. But in a `<script>` tag you should only put JavaScript, not HTML tags. The content of `<iframe>` only gets displayed when the browser doesn't display the iframe. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting

Comment: You would need it to correlate with JavaScript to have a variable for the weekday to associate with the correct HTML file to display though to my understanding.

Comment: Correct, but you cannot nest `<script>` and `<iframe>` in this way. Either use JavaScript on `weekday.htm` to change the `location`. Or use JavaScript on the main page to change the `src` attribute of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put HTML code inside of a `<script>` tag. Generally only JavaScript code is allowed there.

Also anything inside of an `<iframe>` tag usually gets ignored by the browser (only displayed when the browser doesn't support iframes). So it doesn't make sense to put important things there.

Instead you should separate those tags. In your case you probably want to place the `<iframe>` tag previous to the `<script>` tag so that the iframe already exists when the script runs. Then in the script you need to get a reference to the iframe in order to set its `src` attribute to the correct url.